# No overload matches this call, nextjs and typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, next.js, interface

I am trying to display this data in Nextjs fetching data from the restcountries Api v3. The currencies data looks like this:

```
"currencies": {
      "AOA": {
        "name": "Angolan kwanza",
        "symbol": "Kz"
      }
    },
```

I have defined my interfaces like this:

```
interface ICurrencies {
  [key: string]: Currency | undefined;
}

type Currency = {
  [key: string]: string;
};
```

But here, I am getting an error saying that "No overload matches this call". Even though the data is rendering as expected VS code is complaining for this error.

```
<td>
   {/* Display values of the currency object */}
   {country.currencies && Object.entries(Object.values(country.currencies)[0]).map(
                    ([key, value]) => (
                      <li key={key}>
                        {key}: {value}
                      </li>
                    )
                  )}
  </td>
```

Comment: Not 100% sure but it might be because `ICurrencies` allows `undefined`

Comment: Amazing!!
The error is gone!